# JOptionsPane - removing objects

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Basic Black Jack program (the black jack program itself works fine, I just need help revising the Pane part), I cut most of the code out at the end to remove clutter.

How can I remove options from the object array after the user selects a different option (see code for better understanding).

I put the entire JOptionsPane inside a do while loop in case the user decides to click the close button without choosing an option. So I also need help with preventing the user to close the Pane without selecting a button.

I tried using a LinkedList for adding the buttons to the JOptionsPane but it gives me an error saying it requires an array. I used the information from the [docs.oracle.com tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and it only covers using Objects instead of strings.

Can someone offer me an alternative to what I am currently using, because it simply doesn't meet my needs.

```
        Object[] options = {"Stand", "Hit", "Double Down"};

        Object n;

        do {
            n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "Would you like to do?",
            "Options",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            options[0]); //default button title
        }while(n==null);



        if(n.equals(1)) { 
            //code to stand (not accept any more cards)
        }
        else if(n.equals(0)) {
            //code to hit (add another card)
            //code to remove double down option until next hand
        }
        else if(n.equals(2) && canDoubleDown) {
            //code to double down (double bet, and add only one other card to hand)
        }
```

Comment: You'll need to control the options outside of this call, since its state changes depending on what was clicked. Try making it a member variable, or better yet, a class which internally uses a `List`, and provides a `getOptions: Object[]` method.

Comment: That actually makes sense, it solves one of my problems thanks :)